# LEFT/RIGHT join rewrite- Oracle to Postgres migration

Tags: postgresql, outer-join, postgresql-9.4

```
select info.HOUSE_HOLD_ID as HOUSE_HOLD_ID,info.HOUSE_HOLD_NAME 
             as HOUSE_HOLD_NAME,city.CITY_NAME as CITY_NAME,info.FIELD_AREA as FIELD_AREA,
             cdar.resource_name as FIELD_AUDITOR_NAME,cdar.supervisor_name as SUPERVISOR_NAME,
             info.STATUS as STATUS,con.PHONE_NO AS PHONE_NO,con.CELL_NO AS CELL_NO
             from INFORMATION info,CONTACT con,CITY city,
             resource cdar
             where cdar.productid(+)=info.field_auditor_id
             and info.country_id=170 
             and con.country_id=170 and city.country_id=170 
             and info.HOUSE_HOLD_ID=con.HOUSE_HOLD_ID 
             and info.city_id=city.city_id
             and (upper(info.HOUSE_HOLD_ID) like upper('%%') 
                  or upper(info.HOUSE_HOLD_NAME) like upper('%%') or upper(city.CITY_NAME)
                  like upper('%%') or upper(con.PHONE_NO) like upper('%%') 
                  or upper(con.CELL_NO) like upper('%%')
                  or upper(info.FIELD_AREA) like upper('%%') 
                  OR upper(info.STATUS) in ('1','2','3','4') 
                  OR upper(cdar.RESOURCE_NAME) like upper('%%'))
```

We are converting the above query from Oracle to Postgres and I want write `cdar.productid(+)=info.field_auditor_id` separately outside of the query, like using LEFT/RIGHT join here. Sorry to paste all the code like this from our app.

Comment: Hi. If you use use (+) but not with all occurrences of a table alias in a given condition then you get an inner join not a left join. See the documentation on left join. So this code does not do a left join. Please read & act on [mcve]. Also please don't say you're sorry when you're not sorry enough to put in appropriate effort.

Comment: if I'd understood better, I'd have given certain examples. @philipxy i couldn't so had to copy as is.

Comment: What exactly is your question? "write separately outside of the query" is not clear. Do you just want to use join on syntax instead of (+)? Where did you get stuck reading what (+) & left join on do and applying that? If you have had a problem, what is it? What is the smallest DDL, example input & output & query with that problem? Also now that you know that your query doesn't actually do a left join, do you want code that does what that query does or do you want code that actually does a left join? If the former, *just drop the (+)*; otherwise what *do* you want?--you haven't said or shown.

Answer (score 0):

Translate it to a standard SQL join like this:

```
SELECT ...
FROM information info
   JOIN contact con ON info.house_hold_id = con.house_hold_id
   JOIN city city ON info.city_id = city.city_id
   LEFT JOIN resource cdar ON cdar.productid = info.field_auditor_id
WHERE ...
```

Remove the join conditions from the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: My first comment on the question points out that since they don't use (+) with every occurence of cdar the (+) is ignored. Re clarity of the question the title suggests they are mapping (+) to an outer join on but the wording of the question is a mess that you are guessing about.

Comment: That is an accurate observation, and I am indeed guessing.